# Joomla: Using JDatabaseQuery to represent an insert .. select query?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

So I need to run a long(ish) query to insert a new row into a table, based on values of another row elsewhere in the database. This is running in Joomla 3.1.5

Typically, you can use [MySql's `INSERT .. SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) to easily do this, but I'm looking for a way to keep close to [Joomla's query builder](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase), example:

```
<?php

// ...

// Base Tables & Columns.

$my_table = '#__my_table';

$columns = array('column_one', 'column_two');

// Set up the database and query.

$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Escape / quote the table name.
$my_table = $db->quoteName($my_table);

// Escape all columns.
$cols = array_map(array($db, 'quoteName'), $cols);

$query
    ->insert($my_table)
    ->columns($columns)
    // E.g. ->select( ... )->from( ... ) ...

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->query();

// ...

?>
```

Of course, the example comment won't work, but I was wondering if there was a way which would allow me to perform something similar (without needing to run a separate query elsewhere).

Naturally, if there's no way to perform this type of query, I can just drop to using a raw query string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docblocks of many JDatabaseQuery methods include the following statement

```
 * Note that you must not mix insert, update, delete and select method calls when building a query.
```

This is because ... to over simplify but as an example how would we know which list of columns (or which where clause etc) to put where when we are building the query.

But there are ways that you can get around this limitation by building your query in a slightly more complex way (which is fair since it's a more complex query). So for example

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$queryselect = $db->getQuery(true);
$queryselect->select($db->quoteName(array('id','title','alias')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
$selectString = $queryselect->__toString();


$queryInsert = $db->getQuery(true);
$queryInsert->columns($db->quoteName(array('id','title','alias')))
->insert($db->quotename('#__newtable'));

$db->setQuery($queryInsert . $selectString);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: Nifty idea. I've used `__toString()` previously, but didn't think about connecting those two up. Thanks for the great advice.

Comment: This kindof works for me, it concatenates the query but it keeps dropping the columns off the main query??

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at this and without seeing your code it is really hard for me to respond. Maybe it would be good to post a new question or you could post a question on the joomla stackexchange site [joomla.se].